# Dissolve multiple rows straight into one layer and add OIDs into table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, dissolve

I am currently running this script to direct multiple dissolves of a polygon layer

```
FC = "BLPUsCavPlace"
TABLE = "BLPUsCavPlaceContigBLPUs"
FIELDS = ["blpuid", "contigid"]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(TABLE, FIELDS) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        OID1 = str(int(row[0]))
        OID2 = str(int(row[1]))
        SQL = "OBJECTID = %s OR OBJECTID = %s"%(OID1, OID2)
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC, "TEMP_LYR", SQL)
        OUTPUT_NAME = "Dissolve_%s_%s"%(OID1, OID2)
        arcpy.Dissolve_management("TEMP_LYR", OUTPUT_NAME)
        arcpy.Delete_management("TEMP_LYR")
```

However, this knocks out individual dissolved layers. I can always append them afterwards, but I would like to keep it clean and write them straight into another polygon layer called BLPUsCavPlaceDissolved. I would also like each row to contain the two OIDs that were dissolved, so there would be two extra columns called OID1 and OID2 that record them in the layer. Is this possible? Or will dissolve only ever create individual layers?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the quesion. Is it about preventing Dissolve() from creating new layers ?

Comment: Hi - so this is currently set up to produce OUTPUT_NAME which takes each OID and adds it to the new dissolved feature layer name. However, I will end up with hundreds of layers - I would like them all to be appended directly to my layer called BLPUsCavPlaceDissolved. Furthermore, I want a record of these OIDs inside the table under column headers OID1 and OID2 otherwise I just end up with the new polygon but no record of which two polygons were merged. Because I then want to link to other tables to pull data based on these OIDs. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prevent Dissolve from adding new layers.

There are two things to observe here:

1. The output from `Dissolve()` (`OUTPUT_NAME` in your case) is a feature class, not a layer.
2. By default, the management tools adds resulting feature classes as a new layer

There is an environment setting to control the behaviour in 2: In the beginning of your script, add

```
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False
```

then reset it at the end of your script with

```
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = True
```

`Dissolve()` should then finish the job without throwing up a new layer.

After creating your feature classes, you can append them yourself, and add the final result as a layer if desired.

Comment: thanks - although it wasn't adding them to the map beforehand anyway. i want to avoid the manual appending if possible, is there no way to automatically append the output into an existing layer upon creation? as well as taking the OIDs and inputting them into the same row under separate column headings?

Comment: a quick google search would give you this. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000

Comment: yep i know the append tool once they've been made, i'm just not sure how to write it to take the OIDs and put them in the table also.

Comment: I presume I can put this: arcpy.Append_management(OUTPUT_NAME, BLPUsCavPlaceDissolved, NO_TEST, fieldMappings, ""), can you help me define fieldMappings please?

Comment: or rather I can put TABLE instead of OUTPUT_NAME as the OIDs are under columns blupid and contigid. i then just need to map these to columns OID1 and OID2 in BLPUsCavPlaceDissolved